# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 hang up on splash screen when starting?

Tags: boot, grub2

A red triangle with an exclamation mark prompted me to search for the reason my system was not able to install updates. I found a site that said to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This fixed my issue and the triangle was gone. Then a message popped up and said Ubuntu had a problem. I restarted and Ubuntu hung up on the Ubuntu splash screen. I had made no changes and system had been running fine until today.

It looks like he system may be booting because I am able to access a Confluence server site that I installed. I just cannot get past the Ubuntu
splash screens.

I am able to start up from a USB if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I wanted to add further troubleshooting on my part. I have been able to boot into my original logon screen and desktop. I did this by:

1. While booting - hold down shift key to see GRUB menu
2. Selected recovery mode
3. Select dpkg from recovery menu
4. fix broken packages
5. restart system

Now I am back to what started this problem. During logon, I see an window that says Ubuntu has experienced an internal error. It also says 'If you notice further problems, try restarting the computer.' I did restart yesterday and that is when my problem started. How do I fix the internal error and not be afraid to restart?

Looks like I have obsolete package versions that I need to upgrade based on the 2nd screen capture.

[image: InternalError]

[image]

Comment: Additional info - I have been able to get into grub by holding down the shift key at boot. I selected Advanced options and then selected what I think is an old kernel - 4.10.0-35 -generic. I get a logon screen and after I enter my password, I see a dialog window come up that says a system problem has been detected - it goes away and then I loop back to the logon screen.

Comment: More Info - looks like a video problem. I 'bypassed' my NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 by using onboard HDMI. It allows me to boot into low graphics and says graphics could not be detected and I must configure these myself. Maybe the update/upgrade command(s) I ran wiped out my nvidia drivers because it was working fine before I ran those commands. My system is a Dell XPS 8900, i7-3.4GHz, 16GB RAM and the NVIDIA GT 730.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution. I ran `sudo apt-get update`. To 'apply' the updates, I went to Ubuntu Software and applied the OS updates from there. Once the update had completed, I restarted. There were no problems. I restated one more time to check for stability and it was fine - no errors.

Comment: You should be able to do both update and upgrade, either in terminal or in Ubuntu Software. In terminal run `sudo apt update` to update repositori databases and `sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade packets. OR in Ununtu Software, choose Updates-tab, click on the update icon (round arrow) and when it has finished, click on Update. Personally, I prefer the terminal way, since it is easier to see what goes on.